# How can I check the resolution of my .img raster file in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, resolution

I'm just learning ESRI's ArcMap and I just wanted to know where I can find the resolution of a .IMG raster layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the layer in ArcMap
2. Right-click on the layer and go to its properties
3. The information should be in the Source tab